# Android button is not present on NestedScrollView

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have a layout with NestedScrollView which shows some views but the last one (`b_logout`) is not showing.

I wonder why and how to solve that.

Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
        android:background="?colorToolbarBg"
        android:minHeight="?actionBarSize"
        android:orientation="vertical" />

    <androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/my_drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout
            android:id="@+id/motionLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            app:layoutDescription="@xml/scene_activity_account">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_avatar"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"

                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_avatar" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_username"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="username"
                android:textSize="27sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/iv_avatar" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ll_joined"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_username">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:src="@mipmap/ic_join"
                    android:tint="?colorDayNight" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_when_joined"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Joined "
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/toolbarDivider"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0.5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@color/toolbar_default_bg_day"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/ll_joined" />     
            <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
                android:id="@+id/scrollview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbarDivider">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/rl_scrollview_content"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/rl_likes_main"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_margin="30dp">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/border"
                            android:orientation="horizontal"
                            android:weightSum="2"
                            android:padding="15dp">


                            <RelativeLayout
                                android:id="@+id/rl_likes_from_you"
                                android:layout_width="0dp"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:layout_margin="5dp">

                                <LinearLayout
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                                    android:background="@drawable/border"
                                    android:orientation="vertical"
                                    android:padding="15dp">

                                    <TextView
                                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:text="Label 1: Value 1"
                                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                                    <TextView
                                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:text="Label 2: Value 2"
                                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                                    <TextView
                                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:text="Label 3: Value 3"
                                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                                </LinearLayout>

                                <TextView
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                                    android:background="#b8b8b8"
                                    android:text="   From you   "
                                    android:textColor="?colorNightDay" />

                            </RelativeLayout>
                            <RelativeLayout
                                android:id="@+id/rl_likes_for_you"
                                android:layout_width="0dp"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:layout_margin="5dp">

                                <LinearLayout
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                                    android:background="@drawable/border"
                                    android:orientation="vertical"
                                    android:padding="15dp">

                                    <TextView
                                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:text="Label 1: Value 1"
                                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                                    <TextView
                                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:text="Label 2: Value 2"
                                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                                    <TextView
                                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:text="Label 3: Value 3"
                                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                                </LinearLayout>

                                <TextView
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                                    android:background="#b8b8b8"
                                    android:text="   For you   "
                                    android:textColor="?colorNightDay" />

                            </RelativeLayout>
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                            android:background="#b8b8b8"
                            android:text="@string/likes"
                            android:textColor="?colorNightDay"
                            android:textSize="17sp" />

                    </RelativeLayout>


                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@id/rl_likes_main"

                        android:text="sssssssssssssss s s   s s s  s s s s ss s s  s s s  s s s  s s s s s   s s s  s s s s ss s s  s s s  s s s  s s ss s   s s s  s s s s ss s s  s s s  s s s  s s ss s   s s s  s s s s ss s s  s s s  s s s  s s ss s   s s s  s s s s ss s s  s s s  s s s  s s ss s   s s s  s s s s ss s s  s s s  s s s  s s ss s   s s s  s s s s ss s s  s s s  s s s  s s ss s   s s s  s s s s ss s s  s s s  s s s  s s ss s   s s s  s s s s ss s s  s s s  s s s  s s ss s   s s s  s s s s ss s s  s s s  s s s  s s ss s   s s s  s s s s ss s s  s s s  s s s  s s ss s   s s s  s s s s ss s s  s s s  s s s  s s ss s   s s s  s s s s ss s s  s s s  s s s  s s ss s   s s s  s s s s ss s s  s s s  s s s  s s ss s   s s s  s s s s ss s s  s s s  s s s  s s ss s   s s s  s s s s ss s s  s s s  s s s  s s ss s   s s s  s s s s ss s s  s s s  s s s  s s ss s   s s s  s s s s ss s s  s s s  s s s  s s ss s   s s s  s s s s ss s s  s s s  s s s  s s ss s   s s s  s s s s ss s s  s s s  s s s  s s ss s   s s s  s s s s ss s s  s s s  s s s  s s ss s   s s s  s s s s ss s s  s s s  s s s  s s s s   s s s  s s s s ss s s  s s s  s s s  s s s s   s s s  s s s s ss s s  s s s  s s s  s s s s   s s s  s s s s ss s s  s s s  s s s  s s s s   s s s  s s s s ss s s  s s s  s s s  s s s s   s s s  s s s s ss s s  s s s  s s s  s s s s   s s s  s s s s ss s s  s s s  s s s  s s s s   s s s  s s s s ss s s  s s s  s s s  s s s wks" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/b_logout"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@id/tv"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:text="logout" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

        </androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout>


        <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            app:itemIconTint="?colorDayNight"
            app:menu="@menu/menu_navigation_drawer" />

    </androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you want to design the page , but if

> android:layout_height="wrap_content"

in `androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView` is changed to

> android:layout_height="match_parent"

will show the button.